# Does the JAX-RS Client call registered ContextResolver[s]?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, cdi, apache-tomee

Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_xmlcontent_jaxb.html

I'm having trouble finding whether or not this is in the specification or not, but lets say I want the JAX-RS client to use a custom JAXB Context that I universally manage with CDI:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JaxbContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
    @Inject
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return jaxbContext;
    }
}
```

application code:

```
@Inject
private JaxbContextResolver jaxbContextResolver;

public void test() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.register(jaxbContextResolver);
    client.target("https://example.com").request("application/xml").post(Enity.entity(payload, "application/xml"), Response.class);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the jax-rs client is never calling my 
`jaxbContextResolver.getContext()` method. Are ContextResolver[s] supported on the jax-rs client or is that not in the spec? I did notice that CXF attempts to use a ContextResolver but it's not finding mine:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/AbstractJAXBProvider.java#L479

Comment: Can you please try annotating your `JaxbContextResolver` with `@Produces({"application/xml", "application/*+xml", "text/xml" })` and see how it goes?

Comment: Didn't help :/ It's not called

Comment: Dumb question but is the resolver null (meaning maybe the injection is not working)?

Comment: The resolvers are retrieved by the MessageBodyReader/Writers, which are used for both server and client. So yes, they are used for both server _and_ client side.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha that's a good question, no it is not null, it's definitely being instantiated and mapped by the CDI container. Do you have a link to the spec on that by change? I suspect you're correct